# ajax not work inside callback of upvote (jquery plugin)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using this plugin for a voting system like stackoverflow: https://github.com/janosgyerik/jquery-upvote

But after i followed all instructions, Ajax call do not work !

**Here my javascript code:**

```
$(function() {

var callback = function(data) {
    alert("test1"); // <--------- ALERTED
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/test.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { id: data.id, up: data.upvoted, down: data.downvoted, star: data.starred },
         success: function(data) {
            alert("test2"); // <--------- NOT ALERTED
        }
    });
};
$('#topic').upvote({id: 123, callback: callback});
});
```

**Html code:**

```
 <div id="topic" class="upvote">
    <a class="upvote"></a>
    <span class="count">0</span>
    <a class="downvote"></a>
    <a class="star"></a>
 </div>
```

I get `TEST1` alerted, but `TEST2` don't !

Inside `test.php` i wrote only: `echo "test"; // just for test` and link is right and work well.

Comment: Add the error param to the ajax call (as success). i.e. : `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);}` Then check your console for error.

Comment: So check your console for error.

Comment: I get the message `error` only ! i used it like this since i don't know where i find the console: `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert(textStatus, errorThrown);}`

Comment: [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: I got this error message: `Blocking a multi-origin request (Cross-Origin Request): the "Same Origin" policy does not refer to the remote resource on http: //localhost/test.php. Reason: CORS header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"`